# Converting datetime to date. Why so difficult in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, time, format, converters

Why converting a date like 17/09/2013 00:00:00 to a simple 2013/09/17 keeping it a DateTime object is so hard in C#???

I can't believe it...

Given a string like 17/09/2013 00:00:00, that's what i tried to get it and KEEPING IT DateTime:

```
DateTime x = DateTime.Parse(String.Format(element.data, "yyyy-MM-dd")).Date;
```

nothing, it keeps adding those 00:00:00

```
DateTime x = DateTime.Parse(String.Format(element.data, "dd/MM/yyyy").Replace("/", "-")).Date;
```

Nothing.

I tried other dozen of tricks and things and I didn't succeed...

All the examples on MSDN and their forums make use of string manipulation, which I DON'T WANT, because I need to pass dates to a webservice through a datetime.

How can I transform a Datetime in this format dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss  to just yyyy-MM-dd keeping it a DateTime?

Thanks everyone

Comment: The type is called Date **Time**.  It _always_ has a time.  You can convert it to a string that does not have a time.

Comment: How are you passing it to a web service?

Comment: You're confusing what you see in the debugger (the string representing the date/time) with the value of the object. You don't need to cast nothing, you can pass it as it is.

Comment: `DateTime` contains both `Date` and `Time`, when you extract just `Date`, `Time` part will be truncated. The problem is **you have to use some DateTime format** to display the `DateTime`, it doesn't have any integrated format, it's just `data structure`.

Comment: just use `x.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");` if you want a string representation of the date

Comment: I understand that, but  should I say to the webservice developers "Hey, you have to change the webservice to catch strings, you can't use DateTime without time"?

Nice, lol.

Comment: @user2212907 post the relevant code where you need to use this `Date` value.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the DateTime value with the string representation of that value you get when you debug it (it is actually calling the method DateTime.ToString). The **actual** value of a DateTime is in its Ticks property; the formatting is given in the conversion to string, **a DateTime object does not have any format at all**.

Comment: So, how do I pass a yyyy/MM/dd date to a datetime variable? I can pass it in any format and the webservice will take it anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DateTime does not have `format`. A DateTime always contains the date and time. So it is not possible to have a `DateTime` without `time`. You may try like this:-

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(yourObject.ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string s = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: Will not work if the date separator in your culture is not `/`.

Answer (score 5):

A `DateTime` has no 'format', it just contains the year, the month, the day, the hour, the minutes, and the seconds. You can only format your date when you convert it to a string.

And a `DateTime` contains ALWAYS a date **and a time**! You can't have a `DateTime` without a time.

Answer (score 0):

`/` is a placeholder for your culture's date separator, so you need to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to make it work:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(element.data, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/OUIsbw)</kbd>

[The "/" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator)

If you want to convert it then to a string in this format: `2013/09/17`:

```
string str = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the `DateTime` type is *always* a date *and* a time.  You can set the time to midnight by calling `.Date`, but it cannot be removed.

Internally, the `DateTime` type is represented by a binary value that include the number of `Ticks` since January 1 0001 (by the ISO8601/Gregorian calendar).  A tick is 100 nanoseconds.  It also includes two bits that control the `.Kind` which represents whether the basis is UTC, the local system time zone, or "Unspecified" - meaning it could be from anywhere.

Nowhere does it attempt to omit the time portion of the value, nor does it store strings internally.

If you're just wanting to emit the date as a string, then you can always do something like this:

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
string justTheDate = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

If you're looking for a pure "date without a time" type (not just a string representation) then take a closer look at [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/).  It offers a type called `LocalDate` which is exactly that.